# NUnit3TestExecutor discovered 0 of 1 NUnit test cases using Current Discovery mode, Explicit run

Tags: c#, nunit, visual-studio-2019, specflow

When I run my SpecFlow+NUnit tests from Test Explorer, all tests always run, even if I have selected only some of the tests.

I also see this message which I suspect is related:

```
NUnit3TestExecutor discovered 0 of 1 NUnit test cases using Current Discovery mode, Explicit run
```

In addition, after the tests run, they are still marked as "Not run", even if they succeeded.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I fixed it by upgrading all the nuget packages in the solution to the latest version following advice in https://github.com/nunit/nunit-vs-adapter/issues/125. I don't know why that fixed it, but it did.

After upgrading the nuget packages I got an error:

```
System.IO.FileLoadException : Could not load file or assembly 'nunit.framework, Version=3.13.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2638cd05610744eb' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

This was fixed by following advice at https://github.com/SpecFlowOSS/SpecFlow/issues/2387:

Comment: Similarly on VS 2022 17.4 this net452 project just wouldn't run the tests. Installing `NUnit3TestAdapter` and then upgrading `NUnit` from 3.7.0 to 3.13.3 enabled tests to run in VS Test Explorer. This upgrade modified also `.csproj` to import some nunit related `.props`.

Comment: Adding the `dependentAssembly` for nunit.framework in the app.config of my test project fixed the issue. Make sure to redirect to the version that is referenced by your project, though (redirecting to version 3.13.1 doesn't work if the installed version is 3.13.3, don't copy-paste too fast like me!). I had to manually add the redirect, upgrading (with Nuget package manager) from NUnit 3.8 to 3.13.3 wasn't enough.