# .Net 5 Test Host Crashes when Exception is thrown in a thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-5, vstest

This is the error I get:

```txt
========== Starting test run ==========
NUnit Adapter 4.2.0.0: Test execution started
Running selected tests in C:\Users\itaib\source\repos\TestHostCrashTest\TestHostCrashTest\bin\Debug\net5.0\TestHostCrashTest.dll
   NUnit3TestExecutor discovered 1 of 1 NUnit test cases using Current Discovery mode, Non-Explicit run
The active test run was aborted. Reason: Test host process crashed : Unhandled exception. System.Exception: some value
   at TestHostCrashTest.CrashTest.<>c.<CrashTestHost>b__0_0() in C:\Users\itaib\source\repos\TestHostCrashTest\TestHostCrashTest\CrashTest.cs:line 14
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

========== Test run aborted: 0 Tests (0 Passed, 0 Failed, 0 Skipped) run in < 1 ms ==========
```

when I run this test:

```cs
using NUnit.Framework;
using System.Threading;

namespace TestHostCrashTest
{
    public class CrashTest
    {
        [Test]
        public void CrashTestHost()
        {
            var t = new Thread(() =>
                throw new Exception("some value")
            );

            t.IsBackground = true;
            t.Start();
            t.Join();
        }
    }
}
```

It works well on .net framework 4.6.1 but crashes .net 5.0.

I tried registering `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` with nothing in it but it didn't work. Unfortunately handling the exception gracefully isn't an option at this point.

Any workarounds?

BTW this is the `.csproj` file:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <!--<TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>-->
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="17.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit" Version="3.13.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="4.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NUnit3TestExecutor discovered 0 of 1 NUnit test cases using Current Discovery mode, Explicit run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68288496/nunit3testexecutor-discovered-0-of-1-nunit-test-cases-using-current-discovery-mo)

Comment: No, I already using the most up-to-date NuGets (as you can see in the `.csproj` file) and it's not the same error, as in my case it does find the tests but the exception causes the test host process to crash.

Comment: OK, I retracted my duplicate vote.

Comment: Throwing an unhandled exception from a `Thread` crashed .NET Framework apps too. [Fiddle demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tpmOen).

Comment: yes, of course it crashes the app as one can expect, but what I'm talking about is the test host process, which didn't crash in .net framework and does in .net 5. I'd suppose they'd keep handling unhandled exceptions and fail or pass the test (used to pass the test in .net framework for some reason) but instead they let the test host process to crash...

Comment: I'm running into the same issue in 6.0. Have you been able to resolve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

When you configure your test host, you need to be sure that you are starting your TestHost with app Middleware, because otherwise exceptions are not handled and they will be thrown in tests.